# Embedding "Figure Type" Seaborn Plot in PyQt (pyqtgraph)

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, seaborn, pyqtgraph, matplotlib-widget

I am using a wrapper of PyQt ([pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/)) to build a GUI application.
I wish to embed a [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/) plot within it using the  [MatplotlibWidget](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/matplotlibwidget.html). However, my problem is that the Seaborn wrapper method such as `FacetGrid` do not accept an external figure handle. Moreover, when I try to update the MatplotlibWidget object underlying figure (`.fig`) with the figure produced by the `FacetGrid` it doesn't work (no plot after `draw`). Any suggestion for a workaround?

Comment: Is this problem really related to the pyqtgraph's MatplotlibWidget or would it occur in the same fashion within a usual matplotlib plot? Can you specify what you mean by "when I try to update the MatplotlibWidget object underlying figure (.fig) with the figure produced by the FacetGrid"? How do you update a figure with a figure? Can you show the code that attempts this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seaborn's `Facetgrid` provides a convenience function to quickly connect pandas dataframes to the matplotlib pyplot interface.

However in GUI applications you rarely want to use pyplot, but rather the matplotlib API.

The problem you are facing here is that `Facetgrid` already creates its own `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object (`Facetgrid.fig`). Also, the MatplotlibWidget 
creates its own figure, so you end up with two figures.

Now, let's step back a bit:
In principle it is possible to use a seaborn `Facetgrid` plot in PyQt, by first creating the plot and then providing the resulting figure to the figure canvas (`matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg`). The following is an example of how to do that.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import sys
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")


def seabornplot():
    g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", hue="time", palette="Set1",
                                hue_order=["Dinner", "Lunch"])
    g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w")
    return g.fig


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    send_fig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.fig = seabornplot()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.canvas.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                      QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.canvas.updateGeometry()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("A plot:")

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

While this works fine, it is a bit questionable, if it's useful at all. Creating a plot inside a GUI in most cases has the purpose of beeing updated depending on user interactions. In the example case from above, this is pretty inefficient, as it would require to create a new figure instance, create a new canvas with this figure and replace the old canvas instance with the new one, adding it to the layout.

Note that this problematics is specific to those plotting functions in seaborn, which work on a figure level, like `lmplot`, `factorplot`, `jointplot`, `FacetGrid` and possibly others.
Other functions like `regplot`, `boxplot`, `kdeplot` work on an axes level and accept a matplotlib `axes` object as argument (`sns.regplot(x, y, ax=ax1)`).

---

A **possibile solution** is to first create the subplot axes and later plot to those axes, for example using the [pandas plotting functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot).

```
df.plot(kind="scatter", x=..., y=..., ax=...)
```

where `ax` should be set to the previously created axes.
This allows to update the plot within the GUI. See the example below. Of course normal matplotlib plotting (`ax.plot(x,y)`) or the use of the seaborn axes level function discussed above work equally well.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    send_fig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(121)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(122, sharex=self.ax1, sharey=self.ax1)
        self.axes=[self.ax1, self.ax2]
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.canvas.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                                  QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.canvas.updateGeometry()

        self.dropdown1 = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.dropdown1.addItems(["sex", "time", "smoker"])
        self.dropdown2 = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.dropdown2.addItems(["sex", "time", "smoker", "day"])
        self.dropdown2.setCurrentIndex(2)

        self.dropdown1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update)
        self.dropdown2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("A plot:")

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Select category for subplots"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dropdown1)
        self.layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Select category for markers"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dropdown2)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.show()
        self.update()

    def update(self):

        colors=["b", "r", "g", "y", "k", "c"]
        self.ax1.clear()
        self.ax2.clear()
        cat1 = self.dropdown1.currentText()
        cat2 = self.dropdown2.currentText()
        print cat1, cat2

        for i, value in enumerate(tips[cat1].unique().get_values()):
            print "value ", value
            df = tips.loc[tips[cat1] == value]
            self.axes[i].set_title(cat1 + ": " + value)
            for j, value2 in enumerate(df[cat2].unique().get_values()):
                print "value2 ", value2
                df.loc[ tips[cat2] == value2 ].plot(kind="scatter", x="total_bill", y="tip", 
                                                ax=self.axes[i], c=colors[j], label=value2)
        self.axes[i].legend()   
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

A final word about **pyqtgraph**: I wouldn't call pyqtgraph a wrapper for PyQt but more an extention. Although pyqtgraph ships with its own Qt (which makes it portable and work out of the box), it is also a package one can use from within PyQt. You can therefore add a `GraphicsLayoutWidget` to a PyQt layout simply by

```
self.pgcanvas = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
self.layout().addWidget(self.pgcanvas)
```

The same holds for a [MatplotlibWidget](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/matplotlibwidget.html) (`mw = pg.MatplotlibWidget()`). While you can use this kind of widget, it's merely a convenience wrapper, since all it's doing is finding the correct matplotlib imports and creating a `Figure` and a `FigureCanvas` instance. Unless you are using other pyqtgraph functionality, importing the complete pyqtgraph package just to save 5 lines of code seems a bit overkill to me.

Comment: This is a thorough and good answer, but your first sentence is not accurate.

Comment: @mwaskom Please feel free to correct me, if I'm mistaken. What else would you call `FacetGrid` if not a convenience function?

Comment: Well for starters, it's a class, not a function.

Comment: it should be added that in `PyQt5` it is `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding`

Answer (score 5):

Here is exact copy of the accepted answer but using **PYQT5**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    send_fig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(121)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(122, sharex=self.ax1, sharey=self.ax1)
        self.axes=[self.ax1, self.ax2]
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.canvas.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                                  QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.canvas.updateGeometry()

        self.dropdown1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.dropdown1.addItems(["sex", "time", "smoker"])
        self.dropdown2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.dropdown2.addItems(["sex", "time", "smoker", "day"])
        self.dropdown2.setCurrentIndex(2)

        self.dropdown1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update)
        self.dropdown2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("A plot:")

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Select category for subplots"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dropdown1)
        self.layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Select category for markers"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dropdown2)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.show()
        self.update()

    def update(self):

        colors=["b", "r", "g", "y", "k", "c"]
        self.ax1.clear()
        self.ax2.clear()
        cat1 = self.dropdown1.currentText()
        cat2 = self.dropdown2.currentText()
        print (cat1, cat2)

        for i, value in enumerate(tips[cat1].unique().get_values()):
            print ("value ", value)
            df = tips.loc[tips[cat1] == value]
            self.axes[i].set_title(cat1 + ": " + value)
            for j, value2 in enumerate(df[cat2].unique().get_values()):
                print ("value2 ", value2)
                df.loc[ tips[cat2] == value2 ].plot(kind="scatter", x="total_bill", y="tip", 
                                                ax=self.axes[i], c=colors[j], label=value2)
        self.axes[i].legend()   
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

While any matplotlib plots can be embedded in pyqt5 the same way, it's important to note that the UI could get slow as the sizeof the dataset grows. But I found such approaches handy to parse and plot log files by employing regex functionalities.