# Interactive Plot - Interactive option to change hue

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science

I'm trying to make an interactive bar-plot, where in i can have a drop-down to change the hue of a visualization. For example,

```
sns.barplot(x=df['sex'],y=df['total_bill'],hue=df['smoker'])
sns.barplot(x=df['sex'],y=df['total_bill'],hue=df['time'])
```

[image: Smoker]
[image: Time]

I basically want to combine the 2 plots into 1, where i can have a button-like option to change the hue. Im thinking this can be done with plotly or bokeh.

Comment: https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/   this might help to my knowledge!!

Comment: Spent an hour but can't seem to figure out how. I'll update the post with plotly codes once i'm done trying. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671867/embedding-figure-type-seaborn-plot-in-pyqt-pyqtgraph/41677416#41677416) can help. The question is very broad, so it's hard to identify any actual problem and hence provide an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help someone in the future so i'll put it here. I found the answer using this wonderful library https://altair-viz.github.io/